# How can I modify my EnumWindowNamesProc to work with Lazarus and use a List as a parameter?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

**Overview**

I am trying to enumerate a list of all visible window names and then populate a list passed as a parameter.

In Delphi I was able to get this to work with the following:

```
function EnumWindowNamesProc(wHandle: HWND; List: TStrings): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Title: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  Result := False;

  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
  begin
    if Title <> '' then
    begin
      List.Add(string(Title));
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Then I could call the above like so:

`EnumWindows(@EnumWindowNamesProc, LPARAM(FWindowNames));`

Note: `FWindowNames` is a stringlist created inside a custom class.

---

**Problem**

I am also trying to make the function compatible with Lazarus/FPC but it wont accept the `List: TStrings` parameter.

The compiler error in Lazarus complains about a type mismatch (I have highlighted the important parts):

> Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got " (address of
>   function(**LongWord;TStrings**):LongBool;StdCall) ", expected " (procedure
>   variable type of function(**LongWord;LongInt**):LongBool;StdCall) "

I can stop the compiler complaining by changing the function declaration like so:

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  function EnumWindowNamesProc(wHandle: HWND; Param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
{$ELSE}
  function EnumWindowNamesProc(wHandle: HWND; List: TStrings): BOOL; stdcall;
{$ENDIF}
var
  Title: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  Result := False;

  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
  begin
    if Title <> '' then
    begin
      {$IFDEF FPC}
        // List no longer available
      {$ELSE}
        List.Add(string(Title));
      {$ENDIF}
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

But then I lose my `List` parameter.

I know I could modify the code and use a Listbox1 for example directly inside the function but I was hoping to create a reusable function that does not need to know about VCL/LCL controls, instead I was hoping for a more elegant solution and simply pass a `TStrings` based parameter and add to this instead.

---

**Question:**

So my question is, in Delphi I am able to pass a `TStrings` based parameter to my `EnumWindowNamesProc` but in Lazarus it wont accept it. Is it possible, and if so, how can I modify the code so Lazarus accepts the `List: TStrings` parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. You don't have to lose your `List`.
Just use correct parameters and typecast

```
function EnumWindowNamesProc(wHandle: HWND; List: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Title: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  Result := False;

  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
  begin
    if Title <> '' then
    begin
      TStringList(List).Add(string(Title));
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

EnumWindows(@EnumWindowNamesProc, LPARAM(list));
```

To complete my answer. There is one more option - define the function by yourself with pointer (like in Delphi). Then you can use it the same way.

```
function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc:Pointer; lParam:LPARAM):WINBOOL; external 'user32' name 'EnumWindows';
```

Comment: Great thanks, I never thought of typecasting the LPARAM inside the function.

Comment: Once you've fixed the parameters of your callback to match the API declaration, you *shouldn't* need to use `@` when you pass it to `EnumWindows`. If you have to use `@` to pass a function pointer, then that's a sign something is wrong. (*Sometimes*, it means the API declaration in Windows.pas is wrong, but other times, it means your callback declaration is wrong, so check it out.)

Comment: @RobKennedy thanks for the tip, I thought I needed to use the `@` operator because between testing with Delphi and Lazarus, Lazarus wouldn't compile without it and I kind of left it in there. I will remove it in Delphi to test and see what happens, the compiler might give some useful information. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: Not sure if FPC supports `absolute` but you can also declare `var List: TStringList absolute Param;` that avoids needing a cast and makes reuse with different params very easy.